# Download entire folder

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

Paramiko's `get` method is used to download files from a SFTP server.

Say I have 100 files. Can I download them simultaneously somehow, e.g. by downloading the entire folder in one go? Or do I have to download each file one after another?